# Angular2 router is not working if there is a dot (period .) in query param

Tags: angular2-routing

I am using jwt to generate a token that needs to be passed to Angular2 route as query param.
Generated jwt token has dots (.), and angular2 router is not working when there are dot/period characters as part of the param.
I am also using encodeURIComponent of the generated token, and dot character is not touched by URL encoding.

My Angular router version is 3.4.5

Thanks,
Sudhakar

Comment: I faced a similar issue and I couldn't find a solution, so I simply replaced the dots with another string ('_dot_' for example) and when on the router params substribtion then replaced them again with the dot.

Comment: It don't accept the dot so as @Khalav said replace it with other string